# read() syscall on windows fails to read binary file

Tags: c, windows

I would like to read image file to keep them in memory before using them with SDL. I just realized that open() and read() on windows fails to read my file entirely but on linux/BSD it works!

This is my code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define IMGPATH "rabbit.png"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    struct stat st;
    void *data;
    size_t nbread;

    fd = open(IMGPATH, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        exit(1);

    fstat(fd, &st);

    data = malloc(st.st_size);
    if (data == NULL)
        exit(1);

    nbread = read(fd, data, st.st_size);
    if (nbread != st.st_size)
        printf("Failed to read completely: expected = %ld, read = %ld\n", st.st_size, nbread);
}
```

On windows it will produce: Failed to read completely: expected = 19281, read = 5. perror() says no error and if I try to read() again it does not change and stuck at this 5 byte.

Is there some flag I should add to open() to read binary file?

This is the first PNG bytes file I try to read:

```
0000000 211   P   N   G  \r  \n 032  \n  \0  \0  \0  \r   I   H   D   R
0000010  \0  \0  \0   \  \0  \0  \0   k  \b 006  \0  \0  \0   <FA> 220   <E5>
```

Does it stops reading when '\n' appears?

I don't know how to fix this right now.

PS: please do not says "use libpng" because I just need to get the file buffer into memory before using it with SDL and my graphic library.

Comment: Any reason you are not using fopen() and fread()? Btw you forgot to close the file and return a value for main().

Answer (score 5):

A few points:

1. `read()` is not guaranteed to read the count of bytes specified. It may return early or nothing at all. It's normal to have to call `read()` several times to fill large buffers. This is one of the reasons the [stdio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdio.h) wrappers and [`fread()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) are useful.
2. On Windows, text and binary mode differ. Since you did not specifiy `O_BINARY` in your flags, Windows will handle `'\n'` characters differently for this file. Likely it is returning at the first `'\n'` encountered.
3. It's not necessary to check the file size before reading the file. The `read()` and indeed any wrapper around `read()` will always stop reading at the end of the file.

### Update0

On further observation I see that the 5th and 6th characters are `\r\n`, this is handled specially by Windows when in text mode, and explains the early return as I mentioned above. If you don't pass `O_BINARY` to the `open()` call these 2 characters will be converted to a single `\n`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I will use fopen() with "rb" mode then since it's compatible on Windows and Linux so I don't need any difficult tweak.