# Transfer a big file though socket

Tags: python, c, sockets, winapi

I practice in socket programming, I wrote a code (server: python, client: C/C++) to transfer data though socket. With small file, it works perfectly. Then I try with bigger file, it only transfers part of that file. Here is my code:

**Server**

```
def recv_file_from_client(conn):
    f = open("torecv","wb")
    while(True):
        l = conn.recv(1024)
        if "Done" in l:
            break
        f.write(l)
    f.close()
    print "Done recv"
```

**Client**

```
BOOL SendFile(TCHAR* file) {
    FILE* filewrite = fopen("test.txt", "a");
    FILE* fp = _wfopen(file, L"rb");
    unsigned char buffer[1024] = { NULL };
    int readedChar;
    int total = 0;
    char log[128] = { NULL };
    while ((readedChar = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, fp)) > 0) {
        if (send(s, (const char*)buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) {
            total += readedChar;
            sprintf(log, "%d\n", total);
            fputs(log,filewrite);
        }
        memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
    }
    send(s, "Done", 1024, 0);
    fclose(fp);
    return TRUE;
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: _"client: C/C++"_... There is no such language called C/C++. C and C++ are completely different languages. So choose one and don't spam language tags as much as possible.

Comment: Are there the Ascii values of `"Done"` somewhere in the file?

Comment: You need to open your file in binary mode

Comment: You have to check the return code of `send()`. A value >0 is the number of bytes passed to the send buffer, which can be less than what you want to send. (In non-blocking mode even 0 is possible.) You would have to increase the buffer pointer and to decrease the number of bytes to send accordingly and retry until you reach the end of the buffer. On error a value <0 (-1) is returned. Similar with `fread`: You have the number of items (bytes) in `readedChar`, which may be less than 1024, but you always try to send `sizeof(buffer)`, so you may send undefined/old data from `buffer`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read() syscall on windows fails to read binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182957/read-syscall-on-windows-fails-to-read-binary-file)

Comment: @Fareanor im sorry. i still new to it.

Comment: Unrelated, but `char buffer[1024] = { NULL };` is an anti-idiom. NULL is intended to represent a pointer, not a character. You should write `char buffer[1024] = { '\0' };` to explicitely use a `char` or `char buffer[1024] = { 0};` to have an int implicitely converted to a char.

Comment: @BrianMJ You don't have to be sorry, that was just an advice, we're all here to improve, there's no problem at all :)

Comment: You should add a description of the transfer protocol to the question. When do you open and close the connection? Do you transfer any other data/commands/replies before or after the file contents? (Apart from `"Done"`) Do you want to transfer multiple files in a single connection? When transferring both commands and data over the same data stream, error handling may be difficult, and communication can get out of sync. In your example the Python code may not receive the string `"Done"` in a single block. It may as well be `"Do"` at the end of one block and `"ne"` at the start of the next block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sending code has many logic errors:

- lack of adequate error handling.
- passing the wrong buffer size to `send()` (hint, it won't be 1024 for the last buffer if the file size is not an even multiple of 1024).
- assuming `send()` sends the entire buffer in one go (hint, it rarely does). You need to call `send()` in a loop until the entire buffer has been sent.
- misinterpreting the return value of `send()` (hint, it doesn't return a boolean). It returns the actual number of bytes sent (well, the number of bytes accepted into the socket's internal buffer for transmission in the background).
- adding the wrong value to `total` after each `send()`, since you are assuming `send()` the entire buffer in one go.
- sending a delimiter string at the end of the file, without regard to whether such delimiter may have appeared in the file being sent. It would be safer to instead send the file's size before sending the file's bytes.
- specifying the wrong buffer size when sending the delimiter string (hint, `"Done"` is not 1024 bytes in size).
- leaking the `filewrite` handle. You are not calling `fclose()` for it.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```c
BOOL SendRaw(const void *buffer, int size) {
    const char *ptr = (const char*)buffer;
    int numSent;
    while (size > 0) {
        numSent = send(s, ptr, size, 0);
        if (numSent == -1)
            return FALSE;
        ptr += numSent;
        size -= numSent;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL SendFile(const wchar_t* file) {
    FILE* filewrite = fopen("test.txt", "a");
    if (!filewrite)
        return FALSE;

    FILE* fp = _wfopen(file, L"rb");
    if (!fp) {
        fclose(filewrite);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(filewrite);
        return FALSE;
    }

    long size = ftell(fp);
    if (size == -1L) {
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(filewrite);
        return FALSE;
    }

    rewind(fp);

    uint32_t tmp = htonl(size);
    if (!SendRaw(&tmp, sizeof(tmp))) {
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(filewrite);
        return FALSE;
    }

    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    int numBytes, numSent, total = 0;

    while (size > 0) {
        numBytes = fread(buffer, 1, min(sizeof(buffer), size), fp);
        if (numBytes < 1) {
            fclose(fp);
            fclose(filewrite);
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (!SendRaw(buffer, numBytes)) {
            fclose(fp);
            fclose(filewrite);
            return FALSE;
        }
        size -= numBytes;
        total += numBytes;
        fprintf(filewrite, "%d\n", total);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(filewrite);
    return TRUE;
}
```

```py
import struct

def recv_file_from_client(conn):
    f = open("torecv","wb")
    data = conn.recv(4)
    if not data:
        print "Error recv"
        return
    size = struct.unpack("!I", data)[0]
    while(size > 0):
        data = conn.recv(min(1024, size))
        if not data:
            print "Error recv"
            return
        f.write(data)
        size -= len(data)
    f.close()
    print "Done recv"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, it help me alot to understand what i should doing when send and recv.

Answer (score 4):

`Done` is no more than an arbitrary sequence of 4 bytes. If it is present in the tranfered file, it will stop the transfer. For binary files, the common way is to first send the size and then the file, or to send blocks with a well known structure (for example starting with the block size) and an empty block indicating the end of the file.